# Como utilizar if com EventListener

Tags: aplicação-web

Olá, gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de dar um ' if(element.EventListener('mouseover')... ' no Javascript!

Preciso fazer a seguinte ação:
Ao passar o mouse por cima do elemento x acontece algo e removendo o mouse acontece outra.

Segue código Javascript

```
        <script>
        function effect () {
            var element = document.getElementById('caracters');

            if (element.addEventListener == true) {
                document.getElementById('effect').style.animation = "effectload 2s infinite";
            }else {
                document.getElementById('effect').style.animation = "none";
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('caracters').addEventListener('mouseover', () => effect());
    </script>
```

De imediato, obrigado pela sua ajuda! :)

Comment: objeto.onmouseover = funçäo(){ lógica };

Comment: O que esse `if` deveria fazer? Que condição está tentando verificar?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o evento `mouseleave` que será executado quando o seu cursor sair de cima do seu elemento.

Exemplo:

```
document.getElementById('caracters').addEventListener('mouseleave', () => console.log('saiu'));
```

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado Bruno pela ajuda!